# How to have multiple HTML5 canvas with previous, next and add icon

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a whiteboard based on the html5 canvas and have added many features like pencil, eraser, upload image, upload pdf and so on. Could anyone help me with how to have multiple canvas which can be accessed by the previous and next buttons. I also need an add button for addition of a canvas.I have already built the buttons in html and css  and need help in the javascript.
[This is a picture of the next and previous whiteboard buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5az8.png);  [and here id a picture of the add and previous whiteboard buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAC2A.png). When the page is in the last whiteboard the add icon should be shown. I think there should also be a whiteboard limit which would help conserve the browser memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of adding multiple canvas you could use only on canvas,

1. on add canvas button , save this state of canvas and clear it
2. on pressing previous save this state of canvas and load previous state( and same for next)
3. in this way you won't have to worry about creating too many canvas and run into memory leak problem also
4. so basically you will have one canvas and array of state which you will load based on the number